# Oracle Data lng in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, oracle10g

Hello everyone I will connect php with oracle 10g database but I have a problem with data language when I select data  .

I have Arabic language  in database >

this is my code:

```
$db = oci_connect('UserNAme','Pass','localhost/orcl');

if($db){
$item = oci_parse($db,"select * from Test");
oci_execute($item);
    $item_m = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252",$item);
    $information=oci_fetch_array($item_m, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
    do {                                        
        printf("<input type='button' class='btn' value='%s' onclick='add(%s,%s)'  /><br />",$information['NAME'],$information['PRICE'],$information['CODE']);
    } while($information=oci_fetch_array($item_m, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS));
}
```

And I try like this:

```
$db = oci_connect('UserNAme','Pass','localhost/orcl');
```

if($db){

```
$item = oci_parse($db,"select * from Test");
oci_execute($item);



        $information=oci_fetch_array($item, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
            $info=iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252",$information);

                do{                                     
                    printf("<input type='button' class='btn' value='%s' onclick='add(%s,%s)'  /><br />",$info['NAME'],$info['PRICE'],$information['CODE']);
                    }

                while($info=oci_fetch_array($item, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS));
```

}

---

and I will be try to change nls_lang in registry

But the Arabic Language display Like this " ???????????" OR "ظ؟؟ظًظظ.... "

whats the problem ???? 
and thank You all .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `do/while` for fetching from a database. It tends to cause the EXACT type of logic flow error you're suffering from. You do your utf -> win1252 conversion ONCE outside of the loop, then never convert the REST of the db results inside the loop.

Try

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array(..)) {
   $info = iconv(....);
   printf(....);
}
```

instead. No need to call oci_fetch twice, you do your conversion only if some data was actually received from the database, and whoever has to maintain this code after you won't scratch your head at the "backwards" logic of a do/while.

Comment: thank u ... ok now everything alright without Arabic language  .!!! 
the Arabic language    display like this "????" .. why ?
in sql plus every character its ok , but the problem  in php page

Comment: you need to use the SAME character set throughout your entire system. browser->server->database->server->browser. if any stage uses a DIFFERENT char set, you get `?` and other mangled chars.

Comment: ok all data in database in Arabic language and i write meta cod to encoding utf-8 ... in sql database i write after connect to database 
<sql_query('set names utf-8')> and Arabic language display correct>
but i want to connect with oracle database I have problem with Arabic language And I do not find a solution in the forums and websites